# How to get jQuery auto-complete "tagify" values in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using [Tagify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shLtB.png), which is basically using jQuery Autocomplete,

references :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery.tagify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../../Styles/jqueryTagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Script :

```
<script>
        var myTextArea = $("#txtbox").tagify();
        myTextArea.tagify('inputField').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Demo.aspx/GetKeyword",
                    data: "{'match': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item,
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            position: { of: myTextArea.tagify('containerDiv') },
            close: function(event, ui) { myTextArea.tagify('add'); },
        });
        $('form').submit( function() {
             var tagStr = $("#txtbox").tagify('serialize');
             alert( "Got tags: " + tagStr );
             return false;
        });
      </script>
```

HTML is :

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Get Values" />
```

So when we clicked on submit button, we get tags value from here

> var tagStr = $("#txtbox").tagify('serialize');

and when I clicked on `getvalues` the result like this
[image]

How could I get those values in the Code Behind in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a hidden field in html:

```
<input id="hiddenTags" name="tags" type="hidden"/>
```

and update submit js:

```
 $('form').submit( function() {
         var tagStr = $("#txtbox").tagify('serialize');
         alert( "Got tags: " + tagStr );
         $('#hiddenTags').val(tagStr);
         return false;
    });
```

now you can get tags in c#:

```
string tags = Request.Form["tags"];
```

Comment: i am not able to write Response.Request["tags"]; in code behind it says "Cannot access internal property "request" here" , i took one aspx button and onclick event i wrote that

Comment: I'm sorry, it's Request.Form["tags"]

Comment: thank you, but i want aspx button , when i click on it..i want to tags string....here..what happen if i want to get result i must click on <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Get Values" />, what i was expect that, just click on one aspx button and get values

Comment: you can set aspx button's OnClientClick attribute to execute js submit event to set tags value into hidden filed

Comment: yes, you can. OnClientClick="$('#hiddenTags').val($('#txtbox').tagify('serialize'))"